# Neo4j labels performance

Tags: performance, neo4j

How does the usage of shared labels among similar groups affect each other performance? How much a widely used label will impact on small groups that use it as super-group definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up populating a small db to test how very different size of labeled groups can affect each others performance. The result is that you can freely make use of any number of labels without any significant impact on performance provided that in this scenario you specify them from the more specific to the more generic:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match n:Test return count(n);
==> +----------+
==> | count(n) |
==> +----------+
==> | 189222   |
==> +----------+
==> 1 row
==> 1571 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ match n:Test:One return count(n);
==> +----------+
==> | count(n) |
==> +----------+
==> | 170216   |
==> +----------+
==> 1 row
==> 1534 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ match n:Test:Two return count(n);
==> +----------+
==> | count(n) |
==> +----------+
==> | 19006    |
==> +----------+
==> 1 row
==> 526 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ match n:TestTwo return count(n);
==> +----------+
==> | count(n) |
==> +----------+
==> | 19082    |
==> +----------+
==> 1 row
==> 329 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ match n:Two:Test return count(n);
==> +----------+
==> | count(n) |
==> +----------+
==> | 19006    |
==> +----------+
==> 1 row
==> 306 ms
```

(the execution times displayed are averages of multiple queries)

Comment: Thanks for the test! Would be cool to see how it goes with a number of millions of Label members, just to be sure of the effects.

Comment: I agree (unfortunately I'm in no condition to perform such test atm). There is no doubt however that higher numbers of labels qty per node & per db will affect performance. Still there's a reason for whom we're not all writing in assembly despite it's performance :D